# Automate windows forms dialogs with python.net

Tags: python, winforms, dialog, automation, python.net

I am writing an event-handler in python.net, this event-handler is called when a dialog pops up and I want the event handler to answer the dialogs.

I wanted to know if there's a way to answer windows forms dialogs from within the Dialog object itself (something like args.Dialog.DialogResult='OK' etc') or do I have to resort to simulating human interaction (i.e. - bring dialog to front, locate buttons coordinates and simulate a mouse click).

I enclose the sample code I used to handle the events (from Agilent -http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jonnojohnson/Agilent/blob/master/Python_Automation/N5990A_Python_Automation.ipynb ) :

```
def my_DialogPopUp(source, args):
#args.Dialog.ShowDialog()  #Uncomment to show Valiframe dialog box for all cases
msgbox = args.DialogText

# Definition for args.DialogType
#Member name           Value   Description 
#Form                  0       General Form if the dialog is not one of the other dialog types  
#MessageBox            1       Standard Windows.Forms.MessageBox.  
#ConnectionDialog      2       Connection dialog. The dialog which pops up if a connection change is required.  
#UserInformationDialog 3       User Information Dialog, which contains a text and one button.  
#UserDecisionDialog    4       User Decision Dialog, which contains one text and 2 buttons.  
#InfoDialog            5       Info Dialog, which is the same as the UserInformationDialog (obsolete, will be removed in one of the next releases).  

if args.DialogType == 0:
        raw_input('General Form Dialog: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
elif args.DialogType == 1:
        raw_input('Standard Windows.Forms.MessageBox: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
elif args.DialogType == 2:
        raw_input('Connection Dialog: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
elif args.DialogType == 3:
        raw_input('UserInformationDialog: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
elif args.DialogType == 4:
        raw_input('UserDecisionDialog: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
elif args.DialogType == 5:
        raw_input('InfoDialog: '+str(msgbox))
        #  add actions here.....
        #  args.Dialog.ShowDialog() #Uncomment to show dialog box for this case
else:
        raw_input('Message not handled: '+str(msgbox))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate interaction with forms and GUIs, keyboard and mouse, with [AutoPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/), I'm not sure how to assign default values that are passed for your GUI but you could always add some sort of timer that will run your decision if no interaction is provided within a timeframe...